# Section numbering without numbers

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to add a section without a number, but \section* also excludes it from the numbering, so if there is this

```
\section*{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section*{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
```

I get what I want untill Section 2, but I want Subsection 3 to be numbered as "2.1", and it keeps numbering "1.3".

Is there any command that can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want that the titles of the sections are exactly “Section 1”, “Section 2” and so on, so the number at the left is redundant?

Comment: Something like that, yeah, it is redundant

Comment: @Nuria If that is the intention my answer is not the way, you should never number by hand, just change the format so the automatic number comes in the right place.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's not that I'm numbering by hand, I want something like this:
Section 1: Hello!  So Latex makes it: 1 Section 1: Hello! Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Nuria That is exactly what I mean, the markup should be `\section{hello!}`  and just modify the style to put `Section 1: ` at the left instead of just `1. `

Comment: @Nuria I updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a customizable version; by defining `\prefix@subsection`, for instance, you can add some prefix also to the subsection number. Note that you *want* to use `\section` and not `\section*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{Section \thesection: }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Go on}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another application:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{}
\newcommand{\prefix@subsection}{\thesubsection\ - }
\newcommand{\prefix@subsubsection}{\thesubsubsection\ - }
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\section{Another section}
\section{A third section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 37):

You don't want unnumbered sections, you just want to modify the style not to show the number:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@section\else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section aa}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection bbb}
\section{Section zzz}
\subsection{Subsection jjj}

\end{document}
```

---

Or as clarified in comments you *do* want the number, but prefixed with `Section`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@section
  Section \thesection:
  \else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{aa}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection bbb}
\section{zzz}
\subsection{Subsection jjj}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's just what I want, but using the automatic numbering the second section is `Section 1` and I don't know why.

Comment: @Nuria you probably have a `*` left stopping the numbering

Comment: Why not use `titlesec` for this?

Comment: @SeanAllred because I know the latex insides and can suggest a `\@seccntformat` redefinition in my sleep but I would have to read the pacge doc for the package (if I remembered it existed at all:-) freel free to post a package based answer as well, break up my little head-to-head with egreg:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A very good reason indeed :-)

Comment: Can this be extended to subsections?

Answer (score 28):

Consider using the `titlesec` package, which does the hard work for you.
Note that this solution requires you to decide how your sections will look.
As the style is hard-coded in the definition of `\section`,
  I don't believe there is a 'nice' way to access it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}   % The style of the section title
  {}                             % a prefix
  {0pt}                          % How much space exists between the prefix and the title
  {Section \thesection:\quad}    % How the section is represented

% Starred variant
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\begin{document}
\section{Animals}
\subsection{Vertebrates}
\subsection{Invertebrates}
\section{Plants}
\subsection{Fruit-Bearing}
\subsection{Carnivorous}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

(Thanks to @egreg for pointing out the need for a `numberless` variant.)

Comment: `explicit` is not needed; just remove the `#1`; you should also define the `numberless` variant, in any case. David's and my answers have the advantage one doesn't need to guess at the fonts to be used.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the tip, and very true.  Although, I can't think of a (normal) situation where such fonts would be redefined *without* `titlesec`, or at most without some sort of `\@sectionstyle` macro. (I'm actually surprised that `\section` hard-codes it in its definition.)

Comment: @SeanAllred The definition of the sectional units is left to the class; the standard classes don't have a provision for easily changing the fonts, because this is better an expert's job. Everybody can see where the freedom of font choosing in word processors has led.