# Remove numbering from Section and Subsection

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136528/75850) to remove the numbering from sections, but I also don't need numbering on `sub`- and `subsubsection`s.

I tried to add a second def but then the number on `Section` is showed again.
I am fairly new to Latex and I don't really know what is going on in this code block.

Original:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@section\else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Mine:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@section\else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}

\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@subsection\else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you don't want numbering, use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
  \section{A section}
  \subsection{A sub section}
  \subsubsection{A sub sub section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add also  `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` if you want a table of contents with the   sections and subsections, but not the deeper levels.

Answer (score 4):

You have to nest the definition in this way:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@section\else
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@subsection\else
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@subsubsection\else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@section\else
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@subsection\else
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@subsubsection\else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Your "code" works too but it still displays the numbering in the table of contents, so in that case @HarishKumar s answer works better for me.

Comment: @SailorChibi OK. You didn't mention the ToC in your question... :-)

Comment: You are right, I didn't sed, that the code from my linked answer doesn't affect the ToC

Answer (score 3):

That code is aimed to just do the removal from sections. However, in order to remove numbering, the easiest way is to set `secnumdepth` to 0:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

I'll show also how to improve the code you were given for doing several tests.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname prepend@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\prepend@section}{\thesection\quad}
\newcommand{\prepend@subsection}{\thesubsection\quad}
\newcommand{\prepend@subsubsection}{\thesubsubsection\quad}
\makeatother
```

If you want to remove the number in front of subsubsection titles, but keep it in the table of contents (which could be a reason for going this way instead of using `secnumdepth`), just comment out the `\prepend@subsubsection` line.

What happens is that `\subsubsection` will execute `\@seccntformat{subsubsection}` which in turn will do `\csname prepend@subsubsection\endcsname`; if the line is commented out, no definition for `\prepend@subsubsection` is available, so TeX will consider the `\csname...\endcsname` construction equivalent to `\relax`, so it will do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Or the simple option - use the * version.  You have to do it with each section/subsection etc. but many environments have an option where * suppresses the numbering.  E.g. \section*{Introduction}.

Comment: The `\Section*{}` does not show up in the ToC :(