# Roman numerals for section, but none for subsection

Tags: sectioning

I'm using the following command to set my sections to use roman numerals, and I can set subsections to roman or arabic just fine, but I'd like to remove numerals from subsections altogether. I tried using `{}` but it leaves a `.` in front of the subsection.

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{}
```

[image]

It feels like I need something like this, but I can't find a reference as such.

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{empty{subsection}}
```

Comment: Similar to what is mentioned in [Remove numbering from Section and Subsection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244668/5764), you should add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` to your preamble. This will number only up to sectional unit/level 1 = `\section`. Level 2 (`\subsection`) and lower won't be numbered.

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable  example?

Comment: What about using `\subsection*{...}` instead of `\subsection{...}`?