# How to make sure \sectionmark command works from the first section page without affecting running heads at start of chapters?

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

My question is essentially a follow-up to [Sectionmark command ignored in running head of first section page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509606/sectionmark-command-ignored-in-running-head-of-first-section-page). The solution was to replace, in the definition of `\sectionmark`, a higher-level command `\markright` with a lower-level command `\rightmark`. It worked like a charm for the MWE of that question. However, it does not work for me, as in my book some chapters start with a long preamble before any section commands appear. The result is that the running head prints the number and heading of the last section of previous chapter (whereas with a standard definition of `\sectionmark`, no headers appear on those sectionless pages). Note that issuing `\sectionmark` after `\chapter` command does not solve the problem as the running head still contains wrong section number. Here is an MWE adopted from the above question:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\  \thechapter.\  #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\gdef\rightmark{\thesection.\  #1}} % 
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\section{First section of chapter one}
\kant[1-3]
\section{Second section of chapter one}
\kant[8-15]

\chapter{Two}
\kant[1-10]
\section{First section of chapter two: Too much text for a running head}
\sectionmark{First section of chapter two}
\kant[11-15]
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, running heads in the `biblatex` bibliography are also distorted by this definition of `\sectionmark`, but these are harder to reproduce in MWE. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Here is a further MWE demonstrating the problem that if the `\section` command falls on an odd page, the running head on that page shows the full heading rather than the shortened one given in `\sectionmark`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]
{\markboth{\chaptername\  \thechapter.\  #1}{\chaptername\  \thechapter.\  #1}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\section{First section of chapter one}
\kant[1-3]
\section{Second section of chapter one}
\kant[8-15]

\chapter{Two}
\kant[1-15]
\section{First section of chapter two: Too much text for a running head}
\sectionmark{First section of chapter two}
\kant[11-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If there has not been a `\section` then what would you want the running head to show? Perhaps "No section yet specified"? --- GOM

Comment: Making the rash assumption that if the first section in a chapter doesn't come early enough, and the offending running head is on a right-hand page, you can simply, just after the `\chapter` input, `\markright{<chapter title>}`.

Comment: @PeterWilson, I would be happy with an empty running head (as was the case when using the default definition of `\sectionmark`).  Or, as @barbarabeeton suggested, the chapter title... Thank you!

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I have tried and, unfortunately, it changes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The cited answer looks quite wrong. `\rightmark` is not a low-level counterpart to `\markright`: The first command retrieves a value while the second stores it. LaTeX stores the values for good reasons with `\mark` commands and not with a simple `\def` and the answer destroy this.

You seem to want some text if there is no section, so I would suggest that you store something into the right mark with chapter too:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]
{\markboth{\chaptername\  \thechapter.\  #1}{\chaptername\  \thechapter.\  #1}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\section{First section of chapter one}
\kant[1-3]
\section{Second section of chapter one}
\kant[8-15]

\chapter{Two}
\kant[1-10]
\section{First section of chapter two: Too much text for a running head}
\sectionmark{First section of chapter two}
\kant[11-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. However, my core problem is that when `\section' command falls on an odd page, the running head on that page shows argument of `\section'  instead of argument of `\sectionmark' . Thus i tried to use the solution provided in [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509606/sectionmark-command-ignored-in-running-head-of-first-section-page). If that answer is incorrect, can you please suggest a correct one? I will append an MWE to my question.

Comment: see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-runheadtoobig (probably).

Comment: this is embarrassingly simple. It works, including for my 500-pages book. Thank you!