# Numbered subsection within unnumbered section

Tags: sectioning

How to add numbered subsections with unnumbered subsection in article template? I want the following format

```
Unnumbered section
   A First numbered subsection
   B Second numbered subsection
   so on.....
```

Comment: this `\section*{test}
\subsection{test A}
\subsection{test B}` ?

Comment: Maybe [Section numbering without numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136527/35864) can help you.

Comment: What is the number format of numbered sections, numbered subsections and numbered subsections within unnumbered sections?

Comment: @touhami: that is not working. It will produce
test
  0.1 test A
  0.2 test B

But I want 
test
  A test#1
  B test#2
A and B are the subsection numbering.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: A section, A.1 subsection#1, A.2 subsection#2.....
But I want---section, A subsection#1, B subsection#2,.......
The template is article.

Comment: Maybe you need only `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}` together with touhami's solution to get what you want. See [How to change the numbering of \part, \chapter, \section, … to alphabetical, Roman numbers, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3177/35864).

Comment: Are *all* of your sections unnumbered? Or is it just for the first section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The star form of `\section` generates a section without number. Since the subsection number usually is build with the section number, `\thesubsection` needs to be redefined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Unnumbered section}
\subsection{First numbered subsection}
\subsection{Second numbered subsection}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has worked. However, if I want a specific unnumbered section to be having subsection numbering A, B,C, like that but not for the other numbered section, how should I modify the code?

1. Section 1
    1.1 Subsection 1
    1.2 Subsection 2........
2. Section 2
     2.1 Subsection 1
     2.2 Subsection 2....
....................................
....................................
Unnumbered Section
      A Subsection 1
      B Subsection 2....

Template: Article

Comment: The above issue has been solved...