# Need Section Digit with Period in TOC

Tags: macros, article

Here is the code, changes Section format in document body.

```
1 Intro
2 Market Study
3 Stakeholder Opinions
```

to:

```
1. Intro
2. Market Study
3. Stakeholder Opinions
```

From [this StackExchange TeX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136527/section-numbering-without-numbers).

Code for this is.

```
% Put period after section numbers.
\makeatletter
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{\thesection. }%
\makeatother
```

- How to perform action, for TOC to match?

But, what do I write, to redefine style in \tableofcontents command?
Using the article class.

Comment: The `tocloft` package allows a lot of customization of the table of contents format. To do it by hand seems to require changing LaTeX's definition of `\@startsection`: inserting a dot into the `\addcontentsline` command.