# Format Section Style for Dots

Tags: article

Here is the code, changes Section format in document body.

```
1 Start
2 Market Study
3 Stakeholder Opinions
```

to:

```
1. Start
2. Market Study
3. Stakeholder Opinions
```

From [this StackExchange TeX post].

- How to perform action, for TOC to match?

But, what do I write, to redefine style in \tableofcontents command?
Using the article class.

Comment: It is easier to help you if you give a minimal working example, which starts with a document class command, includes all relevant packages, and then has `\begin{document}...\end{document}1st. The code should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Interestingly the answerer down there asked basically the same question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325164/need-section-digit-with-period-in-toc ??? ... but it is a different name ;-)

Comment: This one has the answer. Other marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input:**

```
\usepackage{titletoc,titlesec}

\titlecontents{section}[0pt]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\thecontentslabel.\ }
  {}
  {\titlerule*[8pt]{.}\contentspage}
% ---
\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\Large}{\textbf\thesection.}{6pt}{\bfseries}{\filleft}
\titleformat{name=\subsection}[block]
  {\normalfont}{\textbf\thesubsection}{6pt}{\bfseries}{\filleft}
\titleformat{name=\subsubsection}[block]
  {\normalfont}{\textbf\thesubsubsection}{6pt}{\bfseries}{\filleft}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\
\\
\centerline{\large{\thesubtitle}}
\
\\

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
This is an introduction to the introduction, of an introduction.
\subsection{Main Article}
Now, write your main article here.
\subsection{Supporting Article}
Now, write article here.

\section{Follow-Up}
New section.
\subsection{New Article}
Now, write article here.
\subsection{Following Article}
Now, write article here.
\subsection{Conclusion}
Now, write article here.
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is your answer? It's incomplete ...

Comment: Can you explain, how I can get my TeX above to render output? Or where is the help, for this. Thanks Todd

Comment: There's is **no** rendering of TeX code here. You have to make a screenshot of your output and add it as an image, in `.jpg` or `.png` format

Comment: Hows that. Good enough? (*) And yes, this is a duplicate post, since no one would answer my question, when I managed to actually answer, in spite of the many prominent TeXians on this site. (Deleting it now.)

Comment: I find it is very strange that two different users posts the same question with the same content ;-) And your other question wasn't very supportive to users willing to help you, that's why probably no one answered ;-)

Comment: Can you point me at a proper supportive post, so I can see. How you write posts, which someone with skills would actually answer? Your question need not be very strange, I admit, I created the second user. So I could contribute my new answer. I even asked someone to ask it, with the first post. No one admin or presumed supportive, did anything.

Comment: @ToddValley Experience shows that questions with a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) are usually better received and easier (and therefore quicker) to answer. I think this has several aspects: A MWE gives us something to start with. We don't have to type a new document from scratch and find out how the code fragments from answers might be used and guess which packages are necessary. And a MWE gives more information. If you would have included one this would have shown which documentclass you are using. And especially for toc related questions

Comment: (continued) this is essential. For example koma classes have completely different mechanism to switch on/off these points.  Another point to increase the answering-chance is giving feedback! Not even an hour after your question Dan gave a constructive comment but never got any reply. And to conclude: Many question take a bit of time to get answered, be patient.

Comment: Thank you, yes Dan did reply with a constructive answer. I was not aware the koma classes were so popular? I do find it odd, this is TeX Exchange and not LaTeX Exchange or Koma Exchange, also have seem Beamer. But, must be why Tags are used. There is not a for *latex2 tag, Beamer is very popular. http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags I did find the answer, working with Google and Dan's small hint. I was not able to answer my own question, thus everyone's confusion. I even posted, can someone ask this as a question, and nothing happened.