# How to use biblatex to have a nested bibliography with a nested toc?

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, nesting

Biblatex is really cool, and allows the subdivision of the bibliography into sections based on different filters : for exemple, if I want to print only the articles of my bibliography, I can write :

```
\printbibliography[type=article, title={Articles}]
```

Now, if I want that bibliography to figure in the table of contents, I can add the "heading" argument :

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, type=article, title={Articles}]
```

and my bibliography of articles now figures in my toc.

The thing is, I would like to have a nested bibliography : 
the table of content would look like something like this :

[image: toc with a nested bibliography]

which I achieve easily by writing :

```
\printbibliography[
    heading=bibintoc,
    title={Bibliography}
]
\printbibliography[
    heading=subbibintoc,
    type=article,
    title={Articles}
]
\printbibliography[
    heading=subbibintoc,
    type=book,
    title={Manuals}
]
```

BUT the above code only gets me the toc I want, and not the bibliographies I want. I don't want three bibliographies. I want a "section-like" title saying "Bibliography" (BUT without the numbering, because bibliographies are supposed to not have a numbered title), and then two sub-bibliographies, whereas when I write the above code I have a complete bibliography and then two sub-bibliographies :

[image]

Writing only :

```
\printbibliography[
    heading=subbibintoc,
    type=article,
    title={Articles}
]
\printbibliography[
    heading=subbibintoc,
    type=book,
    title={Manuals}
]
```

doesn't get me what I want neither :

- the toc merges the entries for the two sub-bibs with the entries for the previous section
- the sub-bibs are printed with "subsection-like" titles, but there is no "section-like" title reading "Bibliography".

Writing :

```
\section{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[
    heading=subbibintoc,
    type=article,
    title={Articles}
]
\printbibliography[
    heading=subbibintoc,
    type=book,
    title={Manuals}
]
```

almost gets me what I want, except for the part where the bibliography title is numbered, which ideally it wouldn't.

In my preambule, I have :

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    defernumbers=true,
    style=numeric,
    backref=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

And my .bib file looks like this :

```
@article{ARUCO,
author          = "S. Garrido-Jurado and R. Muñoz-Salinas and F.J. Madrid-Cuevas and M.J. Marín-Jiménez",
journal         = "Pattern Recognition",
%month          = "",
%note           = "",
number          = "6",
pages           = "2280 - 2292",
title           = "Automatic generation and detection of highly reliable fiducial markers under occlusion",
volume          = "47",
year            = "2014",
%issn           = "",
doi             = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2014.01.005",
url             = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320314000235"
}

@article{GenerationFiducialMarkers,
author          = "S. Garrido-Jurado and R. Muñoz-Salinas and F.J. Madrid-Cuevas and R. Medina-Carnicer",
journal         = "Pattern Recognition",
month           = "October",
%note           = "",
%number         = "",
pages           = "481 - 491",
title           = "Generation of fiducial marker dictionaries using mixed integer linear programming",
volume          = "51",
year            = "2015",
%isnn           = "",
doi             = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2015.09.023",
url             = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320315003544"
}

@article{GFDs,
author          = "Dengsheng Zhang and Guojun Lu",
journal         = "Multimedia and Expo",
%month          = "",
%note           = "",
%number         = "",
%pages          = "",
title           = "Generic Fourier descriptor for shape-based image retrieval",
%volume         = "",
year            = "2002",
%issn           = "",
%doi            = "",
%url            = ""
}

@book{DigitalImgProc,
author          = "Rafael C. Gonzalez and Richard E. Woods",
title           = "Digital Image Processing (3rd Edition)",
publisher       = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
%volume         = "",
%number         = "",
%series         = "",
%address        = "",
%edition        = "",
year            = "2006",
%month          = "",
%note           = "",
}
```

I would very grateful if someone knew and explained how to do that, I've been scratching my head for a bit now.

Comment: I suggest you include a `\section` **before** both `\printbibliography`ies. Or revert back to `bibintoc` and use `\chapter` (provided you are using the `book` class).

Comment: @logo_writer : It's not exactly what I want (with a \section command, you get the title to be numbered which I don't want), though it's the closest to what I'm trying to obtain. I'm sorry my post wasn't more clear and precise, I edited.

Comment: If I understand your problem right, you need a no-number section heading? In this case: \section*{Bibliography} does the trick. if you want to change the style of your headings not showing the numbering (but still counting) I'd take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136527/section-numbering-without-numbers#136528

Comment: @pharmarkus : Yes! I didn't know about no-number sections, I'll be sure to check the link you provided. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? (The `bibliography.bib` is the one you posted).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    defernumbers=true,
    style=numeric,
    backref=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\nocite{*}

\chapter*{Bibliography}     
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\markboth{Bibliography}{Bibliography}

\printbibliography[ heading=subbibintoc, type=article, title={Articles} ] 
\printbibliography[ heading=subbibintoc, type=book, title={Manuals} ]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that is indeed what I wanted! I didn't know the * argument on the \sections and \subsections command.