# Start numbering at subsection level, leaving sections unnumbered

Tags: sectioning

I would like to number my sections as follows

```
A section
Another section
A third section
1 - A subsection
1.1 - A subsubsection
1.2 - Another subsubsection
```

As you can see the sections are not numbered but the subsections and the subsubsections are. Is there a simple way to achieve this without resorting to `titlesec`? Thanks.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136527/section-numbering-without-numbers

Comment: I added the specific code for this application in the code suggested for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
    \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
    \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{Section \thesection: }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Hello}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
    \section{Go on}
    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
\end{document}
```